# Body styling for a noscript tag?

Tags: javascript, css, noscript

If no JavaScript is enabled, I want my body to have `overflow:hidden` (no scrollbars).

How can I solve this? Is it possible to use a noscript tag inside of <head> and set specific styles inside of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure

```
<noscript>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            overflow:hidden;
        }
    </style>
</noscript>
```

in your `<head>` would do the job.

But as stated in the other post, it may be better to use CSS for this purpose, and enable overflow for browsers with JavaScript.

Comment: it might work in some browsers but it's certainly not guaranteed to because a `<style>` tag is not valid markup when placed inside a `<noscript>` tag and a `<noscript>` tag isn't valid inside the `<head>` tag.

Answer (score 5):

If you mean the `<body>` of the HTML document, I'd build the HTML as it should be for the users with JS disabled. For example in the CSS file have `body { overflow:hidden }` and then use JavaScript to set the page as it should be for users with JavaScript enabled (i.e. remove the `overflow:hidden` with JavaScript).

Comment: Good idea, especially now that noscript is deprecated.

Comment: +1! Do me a favor and omit inline styles. That would make it perfect :)

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't use inline styles in real life but I figured it'd be more compact for the example. I'll edit the answer :)

Comment: +1  @Neil: where does it say that the noscript element is deprecated?

Comment: @Sebastian, my mistake I was under the impression it had been deprecated in HTML5, but a quick look around shows I am utterly wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It's not valid using the `<noscript>` tag inside the head section (it is allowed only inside `<body`>), so you could use this workaround instead (an HTML5 example)

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html lang="en">
     <head>
         <script>document.documentElement.className = 'js';</script>
         <style>
             body { overflow: hidden; }
             html.js body { overflow: auto; }
         </style>
     </head>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a super overkill, but just for general knowledge:

[Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) uses a mechanism where it suggest you put the `no-js` class on your html tag. If modernizr runs, it removes the `no-js` class. Using modernizr would be an overkill, but you could do this yourself. In your css you would have:

```
html.no-js body {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion. Common practice, and allows for other no-js styles.