# noscript style no working

Tags: html, css, noscript

hey im making a html document and i want to have it so that when someone visits the page and has noscript enable, it would make the entire page black and display white text saying "enable JavaScript"
here is my code:

```html
<noscript>
<style>
.noscript{
   width: 4000px;
   height: 4000px;
   position: fixed;
   top: 50%;
   left: 60%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
   background: black;
}
.noscriptext{
width: 400px;
   height: 100px;
   position: fixed;
   top: 40%;
   left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center; font-size: 100%;
  color: white;
}

</style>

<div class="noscriptext"><h1>to use this you must enable javascript</h1></div>
</noscript>

<div class="noscript">&nbsp;</div>
```

but it's not working help please?
i tried this one:
[Body styling for a noscript tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254729/body-styling-for-a-noscript-tag) but nothing.
pictures:https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhF4y.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `.noscript` after `. noscriptext` so it's displaying on top. Put `.noscript` before `.noscriptext` or use a `z-index` on `.noscriptext`.

But you can simplify this quite a bit, I would use this instead.

```
<noscript>
<style>
.noscriptext {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  background: black;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
</style>
<div class="noscriptext"><h1>to use this you must enable javascript</h1></div>
</noscript>
```